# Error on running react app

Tags: reactjs

What this error means. I installed react-router, react-dom, react-scripts all latest.

below is code

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css'; 
import App from './App'; 
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'; 
var ReactRouter = require('react-router'); 
var UserInfo = require('./Components/UserInfo'); 
var Router = ReactRouter.Router; 
var Route = ReactRouter.Route; 
var routes = (
            <Router history={ReactRouter.browserHistory}> 
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <Route path="user/:username" component={UserInfo} /> 
            </Route>
            </Router> );
```

App.js file look like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import logo from './logo.svg'; 
import './App.css'; 
var history = require('react-router').browserHistory; 
class App extends Component { 
        submitUser(event) 
        { 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        history.push('/user/${this.refs.inputUser.value}'); 
        }
}
```

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/react-router/es/Redirect.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in 'D:\PROJECTS\react-search\node_modules\react-router\es'

Comment: what's your code?

Comment: Can you post your code in your index.js and app.js files?

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var UserInfo = require('./Components/UserInfo');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;

var routes = (
    <Router history={ReactRouter.browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="user/:username" component={UserInfo} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

Comment: below is my app.js

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
var history = require('react-router').browserHistory;

class App extends Component {

  submitUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.push('/user/${this.refs.inputUser.value}');
  }

Comment: render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="uk-navbar-container uk-margin" uk-navbar>
          <div className="uk-navbar-left">

            <a className="uk-navbar-item uk-logo" href="#">  Github search  &nbsp;
              <span uk-icon="icon: github; ratio: 2.2" className="uk-margin-large-right"></span>
            </a>

Comment: <div className="uk-navbar-item  uk-navbar-right">
              <form onSubmit={this.submitUser}>
                <input className="uk-input uk-form-width-medium"
                  type="text" placeholder="Github UserName...." ref="inputUser" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button className="uk-button uk-button-primary">Search &nbsp;
                <span uk-icon="search" className="uk-margin-small-right"></span>
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div className="uk-navbar-item  uk-navbar-right"></div>  </div>

Comment: </nav>

        <div class="uk-container-large">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;

Answer (score 0):

You say you installed `react-dom`, etc., but did you install `react`?

Do you have a `package.json` file for your app? If so, does it include `react` in the dependencies list? If so, have you tried `npm install`? You should have a directory named `react` in your `node_modules` directory if it was installed correctly.

Comment: ya react is installed by default in package.json

Comment: Have you run `npm install`? Just because `react` is listed in the package file doesn't mean it has been installed yet. You can verify that it is installed by looking for the `react` directory inside your `node_modules` directory.